# ClassNotFoundException whn trying to open Android build

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, crash

Hope you are doing well.
Recently I have updated Unity Version and almost all packages for one of our old games and now stuck on an issue, for which I need help. Tried almost everything :D But didn't manage to resolve the issue. So after successfully building the game and trying to launch it on device, I'm getting the following errors.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mycompany.mygame, PID: 1612
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/wrappers/Wrappers;
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzek.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@22.3.0:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@22.3.0:1)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7724)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:7202)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7070)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:263)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2013)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8164)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.wrappers.Wrappers" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~wWMnafso-cl80rzr01yToQ==/com.mycompany.mygame-memj5xJRNWIrb26_QayQTQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~wWMnafso-cl80rzr01yToQ==/com.mycompany.mygame-memj5xJRNWIrb26_QayQTQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~wWMnafso-cl80rzr01yToQ==/com.mycompany.mygame-memj5xJRNWIrb26_QayQTQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzek.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@22.3.0:1) 
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@22.3.0:1) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7724) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:7202) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7070) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:263) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2013) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8164) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967) 
E/AppLovinSdk: [DataCollector] Could not collect Google Advertising ID - this will negatively impact your eCPMs! Please integrate the Google Play Services SDK into your application. More info can be found online at http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html. If you're sure you've integrated the SDK and are still seeing this message, you may need to add a ProGuard exception: -keep public class com.google.android.gms.** { public protected *; }
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/Preconditions;
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.<init>(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier@@17.1.0:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier@@17.1.0:1)
        at com.applovin.impl.sdk.utils.d.collectGoogleAdvertisingInfo(SourceFile:173)
        at com.applovin.impl.sdk.utils.d.c(SourceFile:142)
        at com.applovin.impl.sdk.utils.d.b(SourceFile:88)
        at com.applovin.impl.sdk.utils.d.a(SourceFile:52)
        at com.applovin.impl.sdk.utils.j$1.run(SourceFile:37)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~wWMnafso-cl80rzr01yToQ==/com.mycompany.mygame-memj5xJRNWIrb26_QayQTQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~wWMnafso-cl80rzr01yToQ==/com.mycompany.mygame-memj5xJRNWIrb26_QayQTQ==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~wWMnafso-cl80rzr01yToQ==/com.mycompany.mygame-memj5xJRNWIrb26_QayQTQ==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:207)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.<init>(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier@@17.1.0:2) 
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier@@17.1.0:1) 
        at com.applovin.impl.sdk.utils.d.collectGoogleAdvertisingInfo(SourceFile:173) 
        at com.applovin.impl.sdk.utils.d.c(SourceFile:142) 
        at com.applovin.impl.sdk.utils.d.b(SourceFile:88) 
        at com.applovin.impl.sdk.utils.d.a(SourceFile:52) 
        at com.applovin.impl.sdk.utils.j$1.run(SourceFile:37) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) 
E/AppLovinSdk: [DataCollector] Unable to determine if Fire OS limited ad tracking is turned on
    android.provider.Settings$SettingNotFoundException: limit_ad_tracking
        at android.provider.Settings$Secure.getIntForUser(Settings.java:5702)
        at android.provider.Settings$Secure.getInt(Settings.java:5692)
        at com.applovin.impl.sdk.utils.d.collectFireOSAdvertisingInfo(SourceFile:219)
        at com.applovin.impl.sdk.utils.d.c(SourceFile:147)
        at com.applovin.impl.sdk.utils.d.b(SourceFile:88)
        at com.applovin.impl.sdk.utils.d.a(SourceFile:52)
        at com.applovin.impl.sdk.utils.j$1.run(SourceFile:37)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Unity Version is 2022

Thanks guys.

UPDATE 1: Proguard file.

```
-keep class com.google.unity.** {
   *;
}
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.**{
   public *;
}
-keep public class com.google.ads.**{
   public *;
}
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-dontobfuscate

-keep class com.google.android.gms.games.leaderboard.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.games.snapshot.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.games.achievement.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.games.event.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.games.stats.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.games.* { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.signin.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.dynamic.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.dynamite.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.tasks.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.security.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.base.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.actions.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.games.bridge.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.api.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataBufferUtils { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.nearby.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions { *; }

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.** { public protected *; }
```

Comment: I think you need to resolve libraries using "External Dependency Manager"

Comment: Force Resolve shows Resolution succeeded (

Comment: May be proguard rename the class name check for proguard

Comment: Yup, already checked. Updated question, pls check.